# Printing locations containing non-zero elements in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

The following code prints row numbers `solution1` which have at least one non-zero element. However, corresponding to these row numbers, how do I also print which locations have non-zero elements `solution2` as shown in the expected output.? For instance, row `1` has non-zero elements at locations `[1,3,4,6]`, row `2` has non-zero elements at locations `[0,2,3,5]`.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        , 423.81345923,   0.        , 407.01354328,
        419.14952534,   0.        , 212.13245959,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [402.93473651,   0.        , 216.08166277, 407.01354328,
          0.        , 414.17017965,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ]])


solution1 = []
for idx, e in enumerate(A):
    if any(e): 
        solution1.append(idx)
print("solution 1 =",solution1)
```

The current output is

```
solution 1 = [1,2]
```

The expected output is

```
solution 1 = [1,2]
solution 2 = [[1,3,4,6],[0,2,3,5]]
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] to pose a clear, precise question? Maybe your question can be inferred, but this is a **question** and answer site. You can see [ask] for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where` to find all coordinates for non zero values first, and then split y index by rows:

```
idx, idy = np.where(A)
np.split(idy, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(idx) != 0) + 1)
# [array([1, 3, 4, 6], dtype=int32), array([0, 2, 3, 5], dtype=int32)]
```

Comment: How do I get the output in this form: ```[[1,3,4,6],[0,2,3,5]]```?

Comment: Just use a list comprehension to convert: `[a.tolist() for a in np.split(idy, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(idx) != 0) + 1)]`